# How can I override a vendor trait that was used by vendor service provider?

Tags: laravel-5.7

So, in my laravel project, i am using some package. My problem is, I need to override a trait which is used by that package's service provider (note:both the trait and the service provider is inside the vendor folder). How can I safely override that trait?

To visualize it,

vendor/foo/bar/XYZ (Trait inside vendor folder)

```
trait XYZ
{
    private function whatever(){
        //default code
    }
}
```

vendor/foo/bar/ABC (Service provider inside vendor folder)

```
class ABC extends ServiceProvider
{
    use XYZ;
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->whatever();
    }
}
```

My question is, how can i override the `whatever` function to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant override the function whatever() as long as it is set to private.
I assume the function is either protected or public.

If so, You can do something following.

```
trait XYZ
{
    public function whatever(){
        echo "hello ";
    }
}

class ABC extends ServiceProvider
{
    use XYZ;
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->whatever();
    }
}

// write this class somewhere in app folder. 
class OverrideWhatever extends ABC{
  function whatever() {
      echo parent::whatever().  "world"; 
  }
}


$test = new OverrideWhatever();
echo $test->whatever();
```

Comment: Sadly, the function is private :( Is there any other way to achieve the result without overiding the function? What if i disable the whatever() function and make another custom function? Is it possible?

Comment: You can.
You are allowed to override and use all the protected and public stuffs by extending the class.

Comment: But it is neither protected nor public function. It is private function. If it is possible, could you please tell me how?

Comment: In that case you can override boot() method as long as it has the access to whatever() method.

Comment: Okay then.. Thanks for the help